# Bash: Using SSH to start a long-running remote command and collect its PID

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, pid

When I do the following, then I have to press `CTRL-c` afterwards or the shell acts weird. Left/right arrows keys e.g. doesn't move correctly and the text is messed up.

```
# read -r pid < <(ssh 10.10.10.46 'sleep 50 & echo $!') ; echo $pid
2135
# Killed by signal 2.
^C
#
```

I need this for a script, so I'd like to know why `CTRL-c` is needed and is it possible to work around it?

**Update**

It looks like it opens an extra Bash shell, and that is the one that needs to be exited.

The command I am actually interesting in is

```
read -r pid < <(ssh 10.10.10.46 "mbuffer -4 -v 0 -q -I 8023 > /tmp/mtest & echo $!"); echo $pid
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be "sleep 50 **&&** echo $!" ?

Comment: Then it waits for `sleep` to finish.

Comment: Why do you need the `sleep 50`?

Comment: @ExplosionPills Updated the OP with the actual command I am interested in.

Comment: @fmcato : OP is creating a zombie process & printing its PID. Jasmine: You need to close stdin/stderr/stdout of the process so that the process truly gets detached.

Comment: Re: "extra bash shell", by the way -- `<()` creates a subshell by nature. That you were running something in that subshell that wasn't exiting (the ssh command) was the immediate issue.

Comment: By the way -- you want to use single-quotes, not double-quotes, for the remote command; otherwise, `$!` is evaluated in the local shell, before ssh is even started!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
read -r pid \
  < <(ssh 10.10.10.46 'nohup mbuffer >/tmp/mtest </dev/null 2>/tmp/mtest.err & echo $!')
```

Three important changes:

- Use of `nohup` (you could also get a similar effect with the bash built-in `disown`)
- Redirection of stdin and stderr to files (preventing them from holding handles that connect, eventually, to your terminal).
- Use of single quotes for the remote command (with double-quotes, expansions happen before `ssh` is started, so the `$!` you get is the PID of the most recently started *local* background process).