# How to assign to a bash variable an ssh remote command the pid while capturing its

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

## Introduction

My question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24490769/bash-using-ssh-to-start-a-long-running-remote-command-and-collect-its-pid), except that I'd like the output from the command to be redirected to a local file instead of a remote one.

The questioner was asking for a way to retrieve the process ID with a command similar to this one, where the mbuffer command wouldn't cause hanging:

`read -r pid < <(ssh 10.10.10.46 "mbuffer -4 -v 0 -q -I 8023 > /tmp/mtest & echo $!"); echo $pid`

The answerer responded with the following command to resolve the problem

```
read -r pid \
 < <(ssh 10.10.10.46 'nohup mbuffer >/tmp/mtest </dev/null 2>/tmp/mtest.err & echo $!')
```

Which is really helpful but still places files on the remote machine, not the local one.

## My Attempts

The following is my attempt to capture a log of the output of $command:

`read -r PID < <(ssh $remote 'nohup $command >&2 & echo $!' 2> $log)`

Which sets PID to the process ID properly but doesn't produce a log.

## Question

How can I capture a log on my local machine of the stdout of my `$command` while still assigning PID to the process ID of `$command`?

Comment: The easiest way is to store the PID in a file, then pulling it via scp. `expect` and `netcat` are alternatives to avoid storing a remote file, but IMO, less robust and not worth the trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach:

```
{ read -r pid;
  # Do whatever you want with $pid of the process on remote machine
  cat > my_local_system_log_file
} <(ssh 10.10.10.46 "mkfifo /tmp/mtest; mbuffer -4 -v 0 -q -I 8023 &> /tmp/mtest & echo $!; cat /tmp/mtest");
```

Basically, the first line is PID & further lines are logs from the process.